# Applying Django 1.6 project settings in PyDev

Tags: django, pydev

I have no problems running the python shell with the `python manage.py -shell` command in the terminal; I can import my modules and make queries on the database and so on. However, in PyDev, even though I can import modules, when I try to access the data stored in my SQLite database, I get this message:

> ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.
>   Please supply the ENGINE value.

Since my project's settings are ok (the site works fine locally), it must have to do with Pydev not applying the project configs. The sequence of starting up the Django/python shell is as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings; settings.configure()

from django.core import management 
import XX.settings as settings 
management.setup_environ(settings)     # This throws an error as setup_environ
                                       # setup_environ is deprecated in Django 1.6
```

The last 3 lines are hard-coded (and were, I gather, working pre-Django 1.6)

I thought doing something like:

from django.conf import settings as djangoSettings
from XX import settings
djangoSettings.configure(settings)

But then I get this error:

> ImportError: Could not import settings ''XX.settings'' (Is it on
>   sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module
>   named 'XX.settings'

And yes, the path is in sys.path.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, after tweaking around a little bit more, I found the problem: I had declared an environment variable in Eclipse's "Python Interpreters", whereas everything should be set up in the project's PyDev properties. I'm leaving the question there in case anyone runs into that same problem.